# Fibonacci function returns negative values when they should be positive

Tags: c#, fibonacci

I tried writing a function to determine the n-th number of Fibonacci series. Fairly simple task, I wrote the method, but for some reason it outputs negative values for higher orders, while the mathematical operations do not create a possibility for such an event. The number variables are defined as integers and also output from the functions is defined as an integer.

Is it set up so that integers bigger than some value become negative? I tried describing the variables as doubles but that didn't change the output, still negative. What am I missing?

raw code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 
namespace Program
{
    class Fibonacci
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            for (int step = 10; step < 51; step +=5)            
            {caller(step);}
 
        }
 
        static void caller(int step)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci number of order {0} is {1}", step, fib(step));
            Console.WriteLine("---");
 
            }
 
        static int fib(int step)
        {
            IDictionary<int, int> fibDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int f = 0;
 
            for (int k = 1; k<step+1; k++)
            {
                if (k <= 2)
                    {f = 1;}
                else
                    {f = fibDict[k-1]+fibDict[k-2];}
 
                fibDict.Add(k, f);
            }
 
            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Fibonacci number of order 10 is 55
---
Fibonacci number of order 15 is 610
---
Fibonacci number of order 20 is 6765
---
Fibonacci number of order 25 is 75025
---
Fibonacci number of order 30 is 832040
---
Fibonacci number of order 35 is 9227465
---
Fibonacci number of order 40 is 102334155
---
Fibonacci number of order 45 is 1134903170
---
Fibonacci number of order 50 is -298632863
---
```

Comment: Hint: what's the largest value that `int` supports, and what is your expectation for what would happen if you were to add 1 to that?

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise you to follow more common bracing conventions - ideally just get your IDE to format the blocks, and use the default settings. Likewise, the earlier you start following .NET naming conventions, the less you'll have to "unlearn" when working with someone who really, really expects you to follow them.

Comment: >largest value that int supports< /
ok that makes sense, funny i didnt think about it but now i can see where the problem lies. thanks!